# Window not resizeable / moveable if onBoxReady() method implemented

Tags: extjs

Simple question...

Looking at [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1cfq) - why am I not able to resize / move the window? If I remove the `onBoxReady()` function, everything works fine...

```
Ext.define('AWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    xtype: 'a-window',
    cls: 'attribute-window',

    me: this,

    items: [{
        ...added some items here... (see fiddle)
    }],

    // this is the function that disables the window move / resize 
    onBoxReady: function() {
        console.log('do something...');
    },

    closable: true,
    draggable: true,
    resizable: true
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`onBoxReady` is a protected method, you need to call the parent method in it:

```
onBoxReady: function(width, height) {
    this.callParent([width, height]);

    console.log('do something...');
}
```